# Nether Portals not linking 1.16.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a nether portal from the roof of the nether linking to the overworld. There is also another portal (more than 8 blocks apart) close to this portal which takes me to a nether fortress.

The problem I am having is that whenever I enter the portal that is supposed to take me back to the roof of the nether, it instead teleports me back to the nether fortress.

I have paired both portals to their exact coordinates, and made sure that they are even facing the same direction.

Is there a reason that this is happening?

Comment: "I have paired both portals to their exact coordinates" - "(more than 8 blocks apart)" - if one of them leads to Nether roof, and another to the fortress, they would be much, much more than 8 blocks apart. Post the actual coordinates. The most likely reason I can guess at this point is you didn't pair the y coordinate at all.

Answer (score 1):

As long as another portal is within 128 blocks of another one, it can still be linked. See [this wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Nether_portals#Pairing_portals). Try creating another portal at least 128 blocks away from the previous one.

Comment: It's this simple if you have a single pair of portals. If you have 4 portals, combining them into 2 reliable, consistent pairs is slightly more complex.